# Symfony assetic issue file does not exist

Tags: symfony, assetic

I tried to resolve my problem all this morning but I didn't find the solution anywhere.

I have a Symfony project and I use Assetic for my css and js files. 
Till today when I ran `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod`, it worked fine.

But now I have this error :

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLocatorFileNotFoundException]
>   The file "C:\wamp\www\PLIE08\app/config/config_=prod.yml" does not exist.

I don't understand why it adds `=` in my file.
Moreover, after running this command I realized that a folder called "=prod" is created in var/cache in addition to the dev and prod folder.

I tried to update, install composer, clear the cache, look in config file if something was wrong but I'm still blocked...

Somebody can tell me why it searchs the bad file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this command `bin/console assetic:dump -e prod` to verify duplicated `=`. Otherwise remove the entire content of the cache/prod folder, doest not `clear:cache`, remove all manually.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
It works ! I didn't think that the other command could change something to my issue.

Comment: Oh my god I feel stupid ! I didn't see that I put php bin/console assetic:dump --env==prod . A simply mistype -_-